# What is the purpose of vertexAttribPointer?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, typescript, webgl

I am writing a game engine using javascript and webgl. To test it out I have written a program that draws a cube. For this program to work vertexAttribPointer must be called after I have called bind buffers but before I call draw triangles. I was wondering what exactly this method did and why I have to call these methods in this order?

My best guess is that it initializes the attribute but I don't understand why it must be called on the client side if that is the case.

I have include some of the source below. Everything is written in typescript. For the full source see [github.com/dkellycollins/nemesis](http://github.com/dkellycollins/nemesis)

Setting up the shader:

```
var cubeShader = new shaderProgram();
cubeShader.addShader(shaders.colorVertexShader);
cubeShader.addShader(shaders.colorFragmentShader);
cubeShader.init();
cubeShader.enableAttrib("position", 3, 4 * (3 + 3), 0);
cubeShader.enableAttrib("color", 3, 4 * (3 + 3), 3 * 4);
```

ShaderProgram:

```
class shaderProgram {
    constructor() {
        this.Id = gl.createProgram();
    }

    public Id;

    public addShader(shader:WebGLShader[]):void {
        if(shader instanceof Array) {
            shader.forEach(s => {
                gl.attachShader(this.Id, s);
            });
        } else {
            gl.attachShader(this.Id, shader);
        }
    }

    public init():void {
        gl.linkProgram(this.Id);
    }

    public setActive() {
        gl.useProgram(this.Id);
    }

    public enableAttrib(attribName: string, index: number, stride:number, offset: number) {
        var attrib = gl.getAttribLocation(this.Id, attribName);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attrib);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(attrib, index, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, offset);
    }

    public setFloatAttrib(attribName:string, value:number) {
        var attrib = gl.getAttribLocation(this.Id, attribName);
        gl.vertexAttrib1f(attrib, value);
    }

    public setMatrix(uniName: string, value: number[]) {
        var uniform = gl.getUniformLocation(this.Id, uniName);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniform, false, value);
    }
}
```

Rendering the cube:

```
public render():void {
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, this._triangles, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

Vertex shader source:

```
attribute vec3 position; //the position of the point
uniform mat4 Pmatrix;
uniform mat4 Vmatrix;
uniform mat4 Mmatrix;
attribute vec3 color; //the color of the point
varying vec3 vColor;
void main(void) { //pre-built function
    gl_Position = Pmatrix*Vmatrix*Mmatrix*vec4(position, 1.); //0. is the z, and 1 is w
    vColor=color;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

it tells WebgL how to interpret the data:

```
gl.vertexAttribPointer(attrib, index, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, offset);
```

this means: for attribute `attrib` there are `index` components of type `gl.FLOAT` that are `not` normalized starting at `offset` and `stride` apart in the `gl.ARRAY_BUFFER` bound at the time of this call.

The client is free to set its data anyway it wishes as long as they can be described as above.

Comment: So why must this be done for attributes? Uniforms don't need to do this. Shouldn't webgl be able to determine the index, offset, and stride just from the fact the attribute is a vec3 or am I missing something?

Comment: It wouldn't be able to figure out stride (that depends entirely on how the programmer interleaved the data, there is a default 0 value for tightly packed though), and some people use half floats or integers or shorts for the data (and the buffer stores just a sequence of bytes without type information)

Comment: I think I understand now. I wasn't putting together that all attributes get their data from the array buffer. Thank you for the help!

Comment: just to be clear, there can be more than one `ARRAY_BUFFER` and every attribute can reference a different buffer. Which buffer that attribute is getting its data from is determined by which buffer was bound to the `ARRAY_BUFFER` bind point at the time `vertexAttribPointer` as called for a particular attribute.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this WebGl2 Fundamentals tutorial](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html) this is necessary to specify how to pull the data out. Also:

> A hidden part of gl.vertexAttribPointer is that it binds the current ARRAY_BUFFER to the attribute. In other words now this attribute is bound to positionBuffer. That means we're free to bind something else to the ARRAY_BUFFER bind point. The attribute will continue to use positionBuffer.